# Adjusting UITable/Cell width

Tags: ios, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I've been working on an app which has included the ECSlidingViewController project to give me a navigation that I can slide in from the left. The navigation links are in an NSArray and displayed dynamically into a UITable using the following piece of code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that the text is way too long in length to display once we view the slide out controller. It now looks like this:

[image]

I would love to be able to reduce the cell width if that is possible or even split the text onto two lines and make it look a lot more like this:

[image]

Any helpful advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same situation recently (although I am using [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) rather than EDSlidingViewController).

My solution was to change the width of the entire UITableView instead by embedding it within another UIView ...

Comment: This works to a degree...I can resize the new UITableView, although my table is no longer populated by my NSArray. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make sure that the datasource and delegate of the UITableView are still set appropriately I guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ECSlidingViewController` version 2 (iOS 7+) you can do this by setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` on the controller that you want to not hide.

For example if you wanted to show from the left the whole controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeLeft;
}
```

There is more examples one GitHub:
https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/tree/master/Examples/LayoutDemo